# python IMAPlib how to move emails with no UIDs into sub folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

I am using the following to move emails into subfolders, however this crashes in some cases because I am told some emails don't have UIDs. Is there an alternative to this to move emails into subfolders without using UIDs?

```
def parse_uid(self, data):
    match = pattern_uid.match(data)
    return match.group('uid')
```

where

```
pattern_uid = re.compile('\d+ \(UID (?P<uid>\d+)\)')
```

Called this way:

```
resp, data = self.m.fetch(str(self.i), "(UID)")
msg_uid = self.parse_uid(data[0].decode())
```

with self.i being the integer id for the given email.

The aim was to copy messages using msg_uid as follows:

```
result = self.m.uid('COPY', msg_uid, 'Inbox/VALORISATIONS/KGI')
print("Result:", result[0])
if result[0] == 'OK':
    mov, data = self.m.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
    self.m.expunge()
    print("Mail moved to subfolder")
```

And this gives for some providers (Allianz, Metzler, KGI, Mitsubishi) the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AutomatePDP_IMAP.py", line 3283, in <module>
    GestionBoitePDP.get_mail_deal_with_it(skipgetpasswords = None)
  File "AutomatePDP_IMAP.py", line 3264, in get_mail_deal_with_it
    msg_uid = self.parse_uid(data[0].decode())
  File "AutomatePDP_IMAP.py", line 111, in parse_uid
    return match.group('uid')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Adding the following condition in the parse_uid function:

```
def parse_uid(self, data):
    match = pattern_uid.match(data)
    if match is not None:
        return match.group('uid')
    else:
        return "UID NA"
```

and then using:

```
if msg_uid != "UID NA":
    result = self.m.uid('COPY', msg_uid,'Inbox/VALORISATIONS/ALAHLI')
    print("Result:", result[0])
    if result[0] == 'OK':
        mov, data = self.m.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
        self.m.expunge()
        print("Mail moved to subfolder")
```

I followed Max's advice and removed self.m.expunge() from the loop and added it after the loop.

Problem solved.

Comment: All messages have a `UID`.  If you didn’t get one, it’s because you requested a message sequence number that didn’t exist.  How did that happen?  You moved (and deleted!) a message, and expunged it, causing all your MSNs to shift!  Don’t call expunge during your loop!  Or use UIDs *everywhere*.

Comment: UID may be in different places of response , try lib that can work with it: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: @Max Yes removing expunge from the loop and adding it afterwards solved the problem Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Max's advice and removed self.m.expunge() from the loop and added it after the loop.